# Spring Batch jobExecution.getStepExecutions is empty

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch 4.3.2. . I am writing Test and found something strange, checkout the following code.

```
JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance).get(0);
System.out.println("jobExecution by getJobExecutions jobExecution.getJobId() " + jobExecution.getJobId());
System.out.println("jobExecution by getJobExecutions jobExecution.getStepExecutions().size() " + jobExecution.getStepExecutions().size());
System.out.println("jobExecution by getJobExecutions jobExecution.getExitStatus()" + jobExecution.getExitStatus());

JobExecution lastJobExecution = this.jobExplorer.getLastJobExecution(jobInstance);
System.out.println("jobExecution by getLastJobExecution lastJobExecution.getJobId() " + lastJobExecution.getJobId());
System.out.println("jobExecution by getLastJobExecution lastJobExecution.getStepExecutions().size() " + lastJobExecution.getStepExecutions().size());
System.out.println("jobExecution by getLastJobExecution lastJobExecution.getExitStatus()" + lastJobExecution.getExitStatus());
```

```
jobExecution by getJobExecutions jobExecution.getJobId() 41
jobExecution by getJobExecutions jobExecution.getStepExecutions().size() 3
jobExecution by getJobExecutions jobExecution.getExitStatus()exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=
jobExecution by getLastJobExecution lastJobExecution.getJobId() 41
jobExecution by getLastJobExecution lastJobExecution.getStepExecutions().size() 0
jobExecution by getLastJobExecution lastJobExecution.getExitStatus()exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=
```

For the same jobExecution i get different results for "getStepExecutions()" depending on how i fetch them.
Do you have any Idea why this could be, or do i something wrong?

Cheers T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the implementation of `SimpleJobExplorer#getLastJobExecution`. Thank you for reporting it. I created an issue for it here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3943 which I planned for the next patch release.